# .htaccess rewrite and subdomains connected to subdirectories

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, subdomain, subdirectory

I have installed wordpress to my public_html/ folder on my host. Now, I want to help my friend to get his own wp blog. I wanted to add a folder public_html/zoran/ where I wanted to install another wp and to add subdomain zoran.example.com to call that folder.

Problem is that .htaccess from public_html/ (my wp installation) is messing .htaccess inside public_html/zoran/ folder. I googled a lot, and figured out that this is impossible to have one .htaccess rules in root folder and other in subfolder (mod rewrite).

I cannot access my cPanel for couple of days now, and it will be unavailable for a few days, I recieved mail about that.

Now, I am at this point. I have moved my wp into public_html/www/ and I stored .htaccess file into public_html/ with following content:

```
# Rewriting conditions
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/ [R,L]

# Identify subdomain as %1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.example\.com
# Check if %1 is directory
RewriteCond %1 !-d
# rewrite the request to the subdomain's subfolder
RewriteRule (.*) %1/$1 [L]
```

Above code redirects example.com to www.example.com, and also, it opens my wp, stored in public_html/www/. But, when I try to go to zoran.example.com, I get 500 error, and that folder has just index.html file in it.

What is happening? How come that www folder works, and folder zoran does not work on same principle?!

Comment: The comments say check if %1 is directory, while the code does the other thing. Remove the `!`, so you end up with `RewriteCond %1 -d`